# I want to explore a folder of network drive through web browser of my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, networking

I want to explore a folder of a network drive(\11.11.11.11\Shared) that is share to all user within network. I have hosted my application into IIS of my local machine that is also in the same network.
We have to only explore the folder of like we done using Run Command and putting the address.

It will work when I run the application though visual studio. But if host the published code into IIS then it will not work.

I am always getting the success response in both the cases(on IIS as well as Visual Studio running mode).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you need to be a little more specific. What does _"will not work"_ mean? Or better: what should actually happen if it works?

Answer (score 0):

1. In IIS create web application.
2. Assign app pool of your choice to application.
3. Under web application add virtual directory and map network folder to this virtual directory.
4. Give read/list permissions on your network folder to app pool's identity.
5. Set directory browsing on web application.